# eclipse Android debugger doesn't know my cellphone

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to run my code with my mobile, but it is always offline
i disconnect USB and connect it again with USB 2 and 3 but doesn't work
my debugger mode is active and I install my mobile driver on my laptop.

`TARGAT = UNKNOWN
[eclipse error][1]`

Comment: Run your app on the device only **after** it's ready for deployment. ALWAYS develop using emulators (several different ones: Different screen sizes and different API Levels)

Comment: because my code need bluetooth service i can't test it with emulators

Comment: i install my driver as i mention in the question

Comment: try to reboot your system and device

Comment: It can be certificate acceptance or driver.

Comment: i reboot both my labtop and cell phone